# Symfony do not log deprecations

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

i want the log to behave like the regular php-log in production.
There is a logrotate in place and the server-logs are analyzed with other tools.

So i set up my config_prod.yml like that:

```
monolog:
use_microseconds: false
handlers:
    main:
        type: error_log
        level: WARNING
    deduplicated:
        type: deduplication
        time: 60
        handler: main
```

Somehow the deprecations (via @trigger_error) appear in my log, too.

Can i disable the logging of the deprecations somehow?
I don't need them in prod but only in dev.

Kind regards.
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to exclude a channel php from your handler

```
use_microseconds: false
handlers:
  main:
    type: error_log
    level: WARNING
  deduplicated:
    type: deduplication
    time: 60
    handler: main
    channels: ['!php']
```

Comment: What does die channel mean here?

Comment: I dont know if deprecated pass sure by channel php but in my project i use many handlers too and i refer to this doc to exclude some part : https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html

Comment: FYI This channel includes more than just deprecations. For example, it also contains messages about uncaught exceptions during rendering of a twig template.

Comment: Additionally, not all deprecations are within this channel. Some deprecations don't have a channel at all.